# Check number of times Oracle SQL Stored Procedure is called

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to find out the number of times a stored procedure is called in last few days in Oracle? Thanks

Comment: AFAIK Impossible without using an Audit table which will contain name and time of proc calling.

Comment: unless your stored procedure itself is logging executions in a table, then I would go with @AnkitBajpai - you need to look at the built in Auditing capabilities in the database https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html#GUID-94381464-53A3-421B-8F13-BD171C867405

Comment: Is there no SQL queries to do that?

Comment: you can also look in v$sqlarea, but the data in there is transient.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the past executions can be tricky. But in case if you wish to setup some kind of monitoring for your execution. You can always do that using `audit execute by access`

`audit execute on <schema_name>.<procedure_name> by access;`

Post this, you can keep monitoring the procedure execution using `dba_audit_trail` view;

`SELECT os_username, username, obj_name, owner 
FROM   dba_audit_trail 
WHERE  obj_name = '<procedure_name>';`